# Why does calling a two-argument function require `.self` whereas calling a one-argument function does not?

Tags: swift, generics, types

In this code:

```
func oneArg<T>(type: T.Type) {}

func twoArgs<T>(type: T.Type, string: String) {}

func example() {
    oneArg(Int)
    twoArgs(Int.self, string: "")
}
```

It's possible to call `oneArg` with a value of `Int`, whereas `twoArgs` must be called with a value of `Int.self` for the `type` parameter.

Why does one require `Int` and the other one require `Int.self`?

---

Here's what this looks like in XCode:

The correct code:

[image: compiles]

The incorrect code with a fixit suggestion:

[image: doesn't compile]

Comment: My guess would be that it can't infer you are attempting to use Int as a Type, and instead you are using it as a declaration

Comment: `oneArg(Int)` still generates a warning from the compiler. I don't know why it doesn't generate an error, though. Maybe a compiler bug?

Comment: You always have to use _Type_.self.

Comment: @keithbhunter I do not get a warning from compiler

Comment: `oneArg(Int)` generates a warning ("missing .self ...") in Xcode 8 beta 6, but not with Xcode 7.3.1. So things changed with Swift 3. – The linked-to "duplicate" has a reference to the corresponding Swift bug.

Comment: @Martin R How could it be a bug, it was presented as a bug two years ago!